# Validating textbox entry through javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to allow only characters in a textbox and space in between two characters.I am trying to avoid any unwanted characters and blank string in following Javascript code.

```
var filter = "^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$";
        var label = $('#<%= txtName.ClientID %>').val();

        if ((label.length > 0) && (label!= '')) {
            if (label.match(/^[a-zA-Z \s]{1,40}$/)) {
                if (label.match(/^\s$/)) {
                    alert("Please Enter a Valid name");
                    return false;
                }
                else {

                    $("#myModal").dialog('open');
                }
            }
            else {
                alert("Please Enter a Valid name");
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Please Enter a Valid name");
        }
```

This is working fine for everything except when user enters more than 1 space in the textbox. I was thinking that label.match(/^\s$/))  will take care of blank string or blank spaces.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use an ASP .NET Regular Expression Validator or a custom validator ? That way, you get both client AND server side validation. Users can easily circumvent the JavaScript validation.

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray  - how do you know that he is using asp.net

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray how do you know he is using .net?

Comment: Because he's using `#<%= txtName.ClientID %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a job for 0 or more (the RegEx `*`)! (Pardon the exclamation, I'm feeling epic this morning)

`/^\s$/` means "contains only one space"

I believe you are looking for

`/^\s*$/` means "contains only zero or more spaces"

Answer (score 0):

you should use + sign in regular expression for more than one entities.suppose if you want multiple spaces then use like var expr=/(\s)+/